# Count how many commits have modified a file extension

Tags: git, version-control, commit

I need to extract some data from git projects and for this purpose, I am working on a script to output the results in the format that I need.

One of the things I want to see is how many commits have updated files of a particular extension. For example, I want to count all the commits that have updated `.tex` files in a project (I don't care if other files were changed as well).

What I am getting from my script seems to make sense, but I would like to know if there is a built-in, similar functionality in git, or a quick workaround to be able to gather this data, in order to validate my output.

Comment: _What I am getting from my script seems to make sense_. Can we see it ?

Comment: I thought about including some snippets, but the point of the question is to see how to use git to provide the answers, so I could run some tests on the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list commits that affected any file matching an extension

```
git log :/*.txt :/**/*.txt
```

(Note that the fist pattern says to look in the worktree root directory, and the second says to look in any directory *under* the root.  In my tests just using `:/*.txt` seems to work, but based on the docs I can't see why.  If anyone can fill in that blank, please do...)

You can simplify the output and then feed it to wc

```
git log --format=%H :/*.txt :/**/*.txt |wc -l
```

You might need to broaden the search, as the above will only show what's reachable from `HEAD`.

```
git log --all --format=%H :/*.txt :/**/*.txt |wc -l
```

You also might have to avoid history simplification.

```
git log --all --full-history --format=%H :/*.txt :/**/*.txt |wc -l
```

There are many other options you can use to control exactly what's included in the output (e.g. `--diff-filter` if you're only interested in certain types of file modification, etc.)

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be on the right track and I am following your logic, but when I run any of the above commands I get something like `no matches found: :/*.c`. I am executing them from the root of the cloned repo. Also, what's the corresponding section in the documentation that I should look at?

Comment: @David - That error doesn't look familiar to me; what type of shell are you running in (bash? Windows CMD? PS? ...), and what verison of git?  If you're in the root directory, you could try just `*.c **/*.c` as your patterns.  You can find more about path syntax at https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary by searching the page for `pathspec`

Comment: The shell is zsh 5.5.1 and git is 2.18.0. I tried the simplified pattern but the error is identical: `zsh: no matches found: *.c`. I've tried it with bash and strangely enough, everything works perfectly. I'll have a look at what is happening. Thanks for the answer and hints!

Comment: @David - I haven't used zsh in a long while, but it seems the shell is pretty aggressive about wanting to resolve wildcards unless you tell it not to.  See https://superuser.com/questions/584249/using-wildcards-in-commands-with-zsh or tl;dr: put quotes around each pattern (`":/*.c" ":/**/*.c"`)

Comment: Quick follow-up: I'd also like to look at files that have no extension (e.g. README, NEWS, etc.) but I had no luck. I've tried using `!` for bash and `^` for zsh, for something like `:/**/!(*.*)`, but it doesn't work as I expected (I've tried a few combinations). Some suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: @David - I'd try `":/*" ":!/*.*"` or some variation on that